# USB device shows twice in IORegistryExplorer when unplugged - as live and as terminated

Tags: macos, usb, kernel-extension

I have a USB device that I have developed a codeless kext for to keep OS X from preemptively capturing it. The kext just makes the device match with a different kext in the IOBluetoothFamily.kext.

I am noticing an odd behavior when I perform the following:

- Reboot just to clear the IO Registry.
- Start IORegistryExplorer.
- Plug a device in, get: registered, matched, active with retain 10, busy 0.
- Unplug device, entry goes red (terminated object).
- Update the registry: Terminated object remains (as expected). Also a non-terminated object shows up with the same contents as the terminated, except not registered, not matched, not active, retain 4, busy 2.
- Clear terminated objects - only the red entry will go away. The other entry remains.

I am not running any other application that would access the device.

Is it possible that the kext I am matching to has a bug?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience IORegistryExplorer (and USB Prober) have a tendency to keep objects alive (often making it impossible to unload kexts), closing IORegistryExplorer tends sorts out the problem.

Comment: I am seeing the same kind of behavior with ioreg from the command line. As I plug/unplug devices, the listing of inactive devices with non-0 retain counts increases.

Comment: Another thing - I have developed an application to work with these USB devices. I have registered for device add/remove notification. I get a notification for addition of all of my devices, but only get the remove notification for the first one. Could that behavior be related, or is that another problem?

Comment: @GTAE86: You may want to ask this in a new question, but in general you should normally receive `kIOTerminatedNotification` notifications when the kext is terminating, unless it implements `requestTerminate` and declines termination, or has multiple parents in the IO Registry. You may want to try using `kextunload` to force termination for those instances (which should send the notification).

Comment: I was following a few models of device notification I had seen in Apple stuff and online. I registered for kIOFirstMatchNotification (device added) and kIOTerminatedNotification. From another example, however I saw instead a call to IOSeviceAddInterestNotification upon device added, and that code works pretty well. I know the kext does not unload when I remove my device - not sure if it should.

Comment: @GTAE86: kexts unload automatically some time after the last instance vanishes, not instantly. I was suggesting `kextunload` to see if your code handling the notifications is getting stuck somehow. I think the main difference between using `IOSeviceAddInterestNotification` and `IOServiceAddMatchingNotification` is the use of an iterator. You may want to make sure that you are iterating all the way through the iterator, otherwise the notification will not be re-armed

Comment: Could be an iteration problem, but I have the IteratorNext in a do/while. I changed it to the IOServiceAddInterestNotification pattern, and it works well. The big difference I see between the two is the latter allows very specific notification on what happens with a given device.